# Can I upgrade Windows 10 Home to Pro on a system running a dual boot with Windows 10 (Home) and Linux Mint?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint

I have a system running a dual boot setup with Linux Mint and Windows 10 Home.
Linux Mint is my daily driver but I want to do some stuff on Windows which requires Windows 10 **Pro**. I already have a new license key for the Pro version but I'm a bit hesitant in just running the upgrade.

Is the update going to destroy my Linux Mint installation?
Is the update going to destroy my Bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can upgrade.

Adding the Pro license just enables the Pro features, it's not a reinstallation (and even if it was, as long as you know what you're doing, dual-boot or not is irrelevant).

Occasionally Windows feature updates changes the boot order but users can always revert it to the previous configuration. This however is unrelated to the "Home to Pro" upgrade.

Comment: I've ran the update/upgrade without any issues. The system restarted about 3 times during the process and my Linux Mint installation and the Bootloader have been untouched.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't affect your Linux Mint installation but it might affect your boot loader. Most computers these days do use UEFI but many use CSM and/or are buggy. The last time I used Linux Mint which was a while ago I had to manually enter its UEFI entry. I also had another machine which would replace any boot loader with "linux" its name with Windows Boot Manager I kid not (it did this even when windows wasn't installed.

If you can open your UEFI boot menu and choose Linux Mint and that boots then you are safe. The worst Windows can do is make itself default which it probably already is.

Comment: **This is very confusing - or revealing of the author's confusion -, misleading, and has little or nothing to do with the question.** The problems you describe are rare and may happen with feature updates of any Windows version, Home, Pro, etc. Adding a Pro license to a Home version just enables the Pro features and at best will make it download additional software, which in itself isn't different than installing any other software.

Comment: +GabrielaGarcia Having reread my answer I agree its spurious. I think the last two sentences were the most relevant while the rest is just my experiences. However there's lots of cases where that upgrade could effect how the system boots. You're making a big assumption that it wouldn't. Plus there is also the common case where dualboot setups use BCD editors which might get replaced when upgrading Windows. Here's an example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help

Comment: All you described can happen with **feature updates**, from one build to another. It can happen regardless of the Windows "flavor", I also mentioned it in my answer. However - and this is the point of contention - you're confusing those with the actual question. Going from Home to Pro is for the most part an "administrative" procedure - add the Pro license and Home is changed to Pro, that's it, the only thing that happens is having new features that previously were unavailable - so your example, again, has nothing to do with it. Please understand what the OP's case is before commenting.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The point of my answer is to reduce the likelihood of an unbootable system. Which is the operative question "is this going to render my installation or bootloader dysfunctional" to paraphrase.

When you say "as long as you know what you're doing" how does that help the OP make this process safer?

Just as an example if the OP had Windows and Mint installed as BIOS legacy then the upgrade could make his bootloader not work. Further as evidence of the experience of the OP in the link I offered in fact the upgrade can lead to an unbootable system.